# QDialog different position using different key combinations

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, key, qdialog

I have this snippet that simulate the closing of a window calling a custom QDialog:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class ExitDialog(QDialog):
    """TODO"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttonSi = QPushButton("Yes")
        self.buttonSi.clicked.connect(self.si_clicked)

        self.buttonNo = QPushButton("No")
        self.buttonNo.clicked.connect(self.no_clicked)

        self.buttonNonUscire = QPushButton("Do not exit")
        self.buttonNonUscire.clicked.connect(self.non_uscire_clicked)

        self.text = QLabel("Do you want to save changes before exit?")
        self.text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1.addWidget(self.text)

        hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox2.addWidget(self.buttonSi)
        hbox2.addWidget(self.buttonNo)
        hbox2.addWidget(self.buttonNonUscire)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(hbox1)
        self.layout.addLayout(hbox2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.value_choosed = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key == Qt.Key_Escape:
            event.ignore()

    def get_choosed_value(self):
        return self.value_choosed

    def si_clicked(self):
        self.value_choosed = 0
        self.close()

    def no_clicked(self):
        self.value_choosed = 1
        self.close()

    def non_uscire_clicked(self):
        self.value_choosed = 2
        self.close()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400,300,400,200)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Exit")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def btn_clicked(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        dialog = ExitDialog()
        dialog.exec_()
        choice = dialog.get_choosed_value()
        if choice == 0:
            event.accept()
        elif choice == 1:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QApplication(["TODO"])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

I notice that when I use the 'x' button of the main window or the key combination ALT+F4 for activate the **ExitDialog**, it's position is on different screen coordinates with respect of using the btn **Exit**.
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5, window manager: GNOME Shell.

How is this possible?

Comment: That might depend on the window system, as Qt usually relies on the underlying platform manager to do all that stuff. What OS and version are you using? If it's Linux, what distro/wm?

Comment: Oh right...I forgot to add such informations! I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5, I edited my question...when I'll be at home I'll also check the window manager with the 'wmctrl' tool, but I'm pretty sure it's GNOME. The stange thing is that the piece of code executed to generate the ExitDialog is the same from the closeEvent of the QWidget window, so I see no reason to place the QDialog in different coordinates.

Comment: Closing a window using the window manager's interface is *not exactly* the same thing as calling `close()`. While the result is almost the same at a higher level, the difference is that in the second case it's an internal request, while in the first it's the dm that request a close (a *spontaneous* event), which could probably put the window in a different state (I know very little about the X11 protocol, so I can't telly you more about this), causing the Qt platform helper to set a different geometry for the dialog, which is also probably due to the fact that you didn't set a parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I actually solved by adding a QTimer at the end of `__init__`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer


class ExitDialog(QDialog):
    """TODO"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttonSi = QPushButton("Yes")
        self.buttonSi.clicked.connect(self.si_clicked)

        self.buttonNo = QPushButton("No")
        self.buttonNo.clicked.connect(self.no_clicked)

        self.buttonNonUscire = QPushButton("Do not exit")
        self.buttonNonUscire.clicked.connect(self.non_uscire_clicked)

        self.text = QLabel("Do you want to save changes before exit?")
        self.text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1.addWidget(self.text)

        hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox2.addWidget(self.buttonSi)
        hbox2.addWidget(self.buttonNo)
        hbox2.addWidget(self.buttonNonUscire)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(hbox1)
        self.layout.addLayout(hbox2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.value_choosed = None

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.setPos)
        self.timer.start(1)

    def setPos(self):
        screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width() - size.width()) // 2, (screen.height() - size.height()) // 2)
        self.timer.stop()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key == Qt.Key_Escape:
            event.ignore()

    def get_choosed_value(self):
        return self.value_choosed

    def si_clicked(self):
        self.value_choosed = 0
        self.close()

    def no_clicked(self):
        self.value_choosed = 1
        self.close()

    def non_uscire_clicked(self):
        self.value_choosed = 2
        self.close()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(400,300,400,200)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton("Exit")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def btn_clicked(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        dialog = ExitDialog()
        dialog.exec_()
        choice = dialog.get_choosed_value()
        if choice == 0:
            event.accept()
        elif choice == 1:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QApplication(["TODO"])
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Don't know if there is way to directly interact with the system's window manager.